# Trigger Dropdown From Nav Item in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, button, triggers, nav

How do you trigger a nav item's dropdown in WordPress when a button is clicked? Hopefully the below image helps illustrate my question. Goal: when the 'View Courses' button is clicked the dropdown under 'Shop Courses' is displayed.

[Button trigger dropdown example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWDQg.jpg)

Comment: For questions about WP, try https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This will probably not get any answers on WPSE, as the answer isn't really WordPress related. If you can provide some relevant code generated from your menu, and the js that you have, then you'll be able to get some help.

Comment: I agree with @HowardE your question is fine here, but it would be helpful to see some code or know what theme you're using.  With many themes this should be possible with a JavaScript onclick function.